# "Method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

Tags: java, android

I just started in Android Studio and I want to make a soundboard, but I keep getting this error (`"Method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"`), when I run my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    Button bt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { ... }        

    Button bt1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate2(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.asta_e);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: you have to post the stacktrace (the exception) you are getting

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` has a method `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` that you override. It has however no method `protected void onCreate2(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, but your code claims to override it.

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is fairly simple, the [`@Override` tag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) adds a compile time check to see if a method is overriding a method from a super class.

And since there is no `onCreate2()` method in any of Android's Activity classes (here `AppCompatActivity`), you cannot override it.

You would have to remove the `@Override` tag to make your code compile, however `onCreate2()` will never execute. For this please take a look at the [Android Activtiy Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html). `OnCreate()` gets called on creation of the activity and the code that is in the method will be executed at that point.

You cannot just put random methods into a class and think that they'll be execute. They have to be called from somewhere, in your case `onCreate()` gets called from its super classes, but `onCreate2()` will never get called and won't compile with *wrong* `@Override` tag.

Comment: `@Override` does not do the overriding, it only adds a compile time check to see if a method is overriding. You can override a method without using `@Override`.